# Is there a command line tool to bulk extract images from a pdf?

Tags: command-line, pdf, image-processing, batch

I have a pdf catalog that was given to me from a client in pdf format. They don't have the images but they're in the pdf.

Is there a way to extract all images from a pdf using a command line tool while preserving it's original file names?

I reviewed this question here: [Extract images from PDF with layer masks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32611/extract-images-from-pdf-with-layer-masks)  but it's for individual images.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The program `pdfimages` from the package `poppler-utils` might be what you are looking for. From the man page:

> Pdfimages  reads  the  PDF  file PDF-file, scans one or more pages, and
>          writes one PPM, PBM, or JPEG file for each  image.

[On newer versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150100/extracting-embedded-images-from-a-pdf) of poppler-utils there is an `all` switch to extract to jpg or png:

```
pdfimages -all input.pdf images/prefix
```

will output files in the form *prefix-nnn.[png|jpg]* in the *images* folder.

Comment: Useful with `-all`: `-p`, which will include the page number in the name of the image files.