# How to programmatically determine DPI of images in PDF file?

Tags: command-line, pdf, display-resolution

I have some PDF files that I want to split apart into TIFF files using `convert` (in order to OCR via `tesseract`). This so far is working great - except that in order to automate the whole process, I need to set the DPI of the `convert` output. Right now, I am using a command like this:

`convert -density 300 myFile.pdf -depth 8 -background white output-%04d.tiff`

... which outputs the PDF files at 300 DPI. However, some PDF files have *lower* DPI (e.g. 150 DPI) which means that I don't want to output them at 300 DPI via `convert` - this creates excessively large TIFF files without any additional information.

I know that there are ways to check the DPI of images in a PDF file by opening Adobe Acrobat and messing around in the "preflight" tools. However, is there a way to determine via the command line the DPI of a particular PDF file?

Answer (score 19):

## Main answer

Since I am interested in the same kind of job (though not necessarily to OCR the PDF files, but to convert them to [DjVu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DjVu) and *then* OCR them), I found this question and the responses lacking (since I needed to guess the DPI of the images with the number of pixels and then use the size as output by [`pdfinfo`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/poppler-utils/pdfinfo.1.en.html) or other tricks---not to mention that the images inside a PDF may have different densities etc.).

After a lot of research more, I found that you can use [`pdfimages`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/poppler-utils/pdfimages.1.en.html) (from package [poppler-utils](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/poppler-utils)) like the following:

```
$ pdfimages -list deptest.pdf
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image     100   100  gray    1   1  image  no         9  0    53    53  169B  14%
   2     1 image     100   100  gray    1   1  ccitt  no   [inline]      53    53  698B  56%
```

Notice the `x-ppi` and `y-ppi` at the listing above. It also lists the format in which the images are stored in the PDF, which is cool (sometimes, it is JBIG2, sometimes JPEG2000 etc.)

Note: The file `deptest.pdf` used above is available [from `pdfsizeopt`'s repository](https://github.com/pts/pdfsizeopt/blob/master/deptest/deptest.pdf).

### The real action

After that, you can simply extract the images with `pdfimages` itself or use `pdftoppm` (also from `poppler-utils`) to render entire pages in many formats that you may like (e.g., tiff, for scanning with `tesseract`).

You can use something like the following (assuming you have created a directory named `imgs` where you will put your images):

```
pdfimages -png Faraway-PRA.pdf imgs/prefix
```

The files will be created inside the directory `imgs` with names starting with `prefix`, as in:

```
$ ls 
prefix-000.png  prefix-047.png  prefix-094.png  prefix-141.png
prefix-001.png  prefix-048.png  prefix-095.png  prefix-142.png
prefix-002.png  prefix-049.png  prefix-096.png  prefix-143.png
prefix-003.png  prefix-050.png  prefix-097.png  prefix-144.png
(...)
```

You can, then, perform any surgery that you see fit with tools like `scantailor` or whatever you like.

## More direct answer

If you just want to OCR a PDF file, you can use a program that is well-maintained and already packaged, namely [ocrmypdf](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ocrmypdf).

Comment: Note that `x-ppi` (x resolution in DPI) and `y-ppi` (y resolution in DPI) are NOT shown on the older versions of `pdfimages` which come with Ubuntu 14.04, for instance. What is available on Ubuntu 18.04, however, does include these values.  `pdfimages -v` on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine shows I have version 0.62.0, which *does* have these features.

Comment: @GabrielStaples, thanks for pointing that out. I thought that Ubuntu 14.04 was already EOL'ed, but it "only" had its Standard Support ended July of 2019 according to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Answer (score 7):

This technique also uses ImageMagick:

```
identify -format "%w x %h %x x %y" DAT_1.tif
```

The output is the size of the image and the dpi:

```
2480 x 3507 300 x 300
```

Comment: I would add a new line to the end of format, in case you want to do *.pdf to process all pdfs in directory. "%w x %h %x x %y\n"

Comment: This does not do what the main question asks. This returns the whole document size and resolution

Comment: The site seems to be broken. [the wayback machine only finds a domain parking from 6 May 2021](http://web.archive.org/web/20210506133836/http://www.wizards-toolkit.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=16110)

Answer (score 2):

I use the following command:

```
convert MyPDF.pdf -print "Size: %wx%h\n" /dev/null
```

and it returns:

```
Size: 380x380
```

Comment: Thanks - this gets the *size* of the pdf images (in your case, 380x380 as it is a square). The DPI is different. On my file that I just ran this command on, I get `Size: 595x842` although the DPI (checking in Acrobat) is around 130