# Why are image files from pdfimages bigger than the PDFs they came from?

Tags: command-line, pdf, image-processing

On Ubuntu 16.04, `pdfimages -all` produces image files whose sum of storage use is greater than the PDF files from which they came.

Is there any explanation for this?  How can I extract image files that are no larger than the size they're using on the `.pdf` without compensating on picture quality?

Note: I've tried an approach that uses the `pdftohtml` command ([Extracting embedded images from a PDF](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150100/extracting-embedded-images-from-a-pdf?lq=1#comment1100727_150106)) but the files don't seem to allow me because of some kind of permission relating to extracting text (I get the error: `Permission Error: Copying of text from this document is not allowed.`).

Comment: It may be because the images are represented within the PDF as *vector graphics* whereas `pdfimage` outputs as *raster images* such as JPEG. It is possible to extract vector graphics directly (to SVG, or EPS) for example using image programs such as `inkscape` - however it may not be easy to automate